# Google maps broken without typing in www

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I attached google map api to my website code. When I visit the site with normal url (www.example.com), the map can work perfectly. But when I ignore www and just type in example.com, the website still working while the map isn't.[image]

Anyone has any solutions to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall the Google Maps API has a whitelist for domains that can use a particular API key.

Are both www.example.com and example.com on the whitelist?

Comment: Thank you, AKX! That helps. I found that in the cloud platform.